# How to print datagrid's all records?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in wpf and I want to print all its records.

I searched and found this code:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
PrintDialog Printdlg = new PrintDialog();
if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
    Size pageSize = new Size(Printdlg.PrintableAreaWidth, Printdlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
    // sizing of the element.
    dgBarnamehBaziha.Measure(pageSize);
    dgBarnamehBaziha.Arrange(new Rect(8, 8, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
    Printdlg.PrintVisual(dgBarnamehBaziha, Title);
}
```

but this code has a problem for me: It prints just records that are shown in DataGrid at the moment of printing. That is, if height of my DataGrid shows only 10 records, only those are printed.

How can I print all records in my DataGrid ?

Comment: i never used it, but shouldn't you use the Items property of your datagrid?

Comment: No my friend...

Comment: Try to put the datagrid in a viewbox, and print that instead of dgBarnamehBaziha

Comment: Do you have `EnableRowVirtualization = "True"` in your `DataGrid` ? if yes try to set it to `False` and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a library here you may want to try.. It accepts a datatable as input which can be constructed from your data source

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238135/WPF-Print-Engine-Part-I